# Indirect casting from class to interface and back

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have one question related to C# inheritance.

```
interface IA { … }

interface IB : IA { … }

class CB : IB { … }
```

Is it okay to cast CB to IA and somewhere later recast from IA to CB?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Just do it! Well tested at compile time. To void runtime error, check if(cb as IA) { ...}.

Comment: `CB to IA` would work fine. `IA to CB` might return null if the object is actually not of `CB` class.